# CSS styling for a boolean React hook button

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have a simple message board with nested comments built in React. I'm trying to add a favorite button (just a button that toggles filled/unfilled contingent on its boolean value). Every tutorial I find involves making a new component, but I'd like to include this in my primary app code (using a hook/useState).

I've tried some various CSS stuff like active, etc. I'm rusty with CSS and a bit lost using it on JSX. Ideally, it'd be a star button that fills/unfills, but I want to figure out the simple basics here first.

```
function Toggle(props) {
  const [toggleState, setToggleState] = useState(false);

  function toggle() {
    setToggleState(toggleState === false? true : false);
  }

  return (
    <div {...props}>
      <Button 
      className={`switch ${toggleState}`} 
      onClick={toggle}>
      Favorite
      </Button>
    </div>
    )
}

Toggle=styled(Toggle)`
//dunno what to put here
```

The button shows up just fine but nothing I try in the style will make it toggle colors (or filled/unfilled) on click. How can I do this?

Comment: Not an answer but just a suggestion, this syntax is more readable `setToggleState(!toggleState);` than this `setToggleState(toggleState === false? true : false);`

Comment: I think you don't really need to use styles-components here, but is just an opinion

Answer (score 1):

First of all this syntax is more readable

```
 function toggle() {
    setToggleState(!toggleState);
  }
```

then you can use this to change the class of your button

```
className={`switch ${toggleState ? "some_class" : "some_other_class"}`}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `styled-components`, you can customize `Button` directly. In `Tagged templates`, switch styles according to `prop`.

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/styled-components-template-pb9z4?fontsize=14&module=%2Fsrc%2FToggle.js)

```js
const Button = styled(Icon)`
  color: ${props => (props.filled ? 'pink' : 'transparent')};
  -webkit-text-stroke: 2px pink;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 0.5em;
  cursor: pointer;
`

function Toggle(props) {
  const [toggleState, setToggleState] = useState(false)

  function toggle() {
    setToggleState(toggleState => !toggleState)
  }

  return (
    <Button filled={toggleState} onClick={toggle}>
      favorite
    </Button>
  )
}
```

---

[Adapting based on props](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#adapting-based-on-props)

Answer (score 0):

Following your code:

```
const StyledToggle=styled(Toggle)`
  &.true {
    //true styles
}
  &.false {
    //false styles
}
`;
```

As you are using css in js you could also pass the state as a prop to the component and read it inside the tagged template:

```
  return (
    <div {...props}>
      <Button 
      toggleState={toggleState}
      onClick={toggle}>
      Favorite
      </Button>
    </div>
    )
}

const StyledToggle = styled(Toggle)`
  font-weight: ${({toggleState}) => toggleState && "bold"};
`;
```